# Using GSON to deserialize generic container with specific objects

Tags: java, android, gson

I have a webservice that returns the same generic container for every request with some basic information. For example, requesting a list of users will give me the following response:

```
{
   "error":false,
   "message":"Message goes here",
   "items":[
      {
         "id":1,
         "name":"Test User 1"
      },
      {
         "id":2,
         "name":"Test User 2"
      }
   ]
}
```

When requesting a different resource, only the list of items will differ:

```
{
   "error":false,
   "message":"Message goes here",
   "items":[
      {
         "id":3,
         "artist":"Artist 1",
         "year":2001
      },
      {
         "id":4,
         "artist":"Artist 2",
         "year":1980
      }
   ]
}
```

In my client I want to map the response on java objects using GSON:

```
public class ArtistRestResponse {
    private boolean error;
    private String message = "";
    private Artist[] items;     
}
```

However, to refactor the common fields and keep me from creating classes for each resource, it would be a logical step to create a generically typed `RestResponse<T>` class:

```
public class RestResponse<T> {
   private boolean error;
   private String message = "";
   private T[] items;           
}
```

The problem is that it is impossible to use `RestResponse<Artist> = new Gson().fromJson(json, RestResponse<Artist>.class);`.
Is there any way use such a construction, or is there a better way to handle the server response?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `TypeToken` here.

```
final TypeToken<RestResponse<Artist>> token = new TypeToken<RestResponse<Artist>>() {};
final Type type = token.getType();
final Gson gson = new Gson();

final RestResponse<Artist> response = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```